# I am trying to build a histogram in python matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code:

```
def histogram(value_array,xlabel):


    mu, sigma = np.mean(value_array), np.std(value_array)
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(value_array, 50, normed=1, 
                facecolor='blue',histtype = "bar", alpha=0.75)
    # add a 'best fit' line
    y = mlab.normpdf( bins, mu, sigma)
    l = plt.plot(bins, y, linewidth=1)
    plt.axis([np.min(value_array), np.max(value_array), np.min(y),np.max(y)])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel("pdf")
    plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]
The scale of the values in the x-axis should either be in the middle of the bar or starting point of the bar. I am not able to understand why it is mis aligned like this. Anyone has faced this issue?

Comment: Please convert this question into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no misalignment here. In order for something to be misaligned you would need to define how it should be aligned first, which you didn't. So the only thing matplotlib knows is that you are plotting some data in the range between 0 and some value and it conveniently places the ticks at multiples of 5 on the axis. If you wanted to label each bar, you would end up with 50 ticklabels, which would then become unreadable. So please state clearly how you would like your plot to look like.